# Magento sitemap with layered navigation urls

Tags: magento, sitemap

I have generated a sitemap.xml from catalog > google sitemap. However, it does not include the URLs with params like layered navigation URLs.

Is there a way to generate a sitemap with these URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Sitemap should be fairly straightforward to generate manually.
Magento stores all of it search friendly urls in a couple of tables all containing 'url'.

Find the table/tables that contain the urls you want added to the sitemap and reformat them into sitemap format.

Something like...

```
SELECT CONCAT('www.mysite.com/', cu.url ) as full_url from core_url cu;
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this to Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap -

$layerBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View');
        $_filters = $layerBlock->getFilters();

```
    $changefreq = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/page/changefreq', $storeId);
    $priority   = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/page/priority', $storeId);

    foreach ($_filters as $_filter) {

        foreach ($_filter->getItems() as $_item){
            $path = explode("?",$_item->getUrl('sitemap'));
            $xml = sprintf('<url><loc>%s</loc><lastmod>%s</lastmod><changefreq>%s</changefreq><priority>%.1f</priority></url>',
                htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . "browse?".$path[1]),
                $date,
                $changefreq,
                $priority
            );
            $io->streamWrite($xml);

        }
    }
```